# Parse CloudCode setup issue in os x console

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I would like to setup Parse.com's CloudCode for an iOS project, but i stuck right at the beginning. I'm not so familiar with the console, so it's sure that it's because my lack of knowledge, but i can't figure it out alone.

I followed the CloudCode guide and everything went good until the point, where i needed to choose the app that i wanna use. The problem is that i typed the name of the app instead of it's number and got an error. I tried to do it again from the beginning, but when i use the `parse new` command i receive this message: `A Parse project already exists in directory`.

Possibly could somebody tell me how can i get to the point again where i can choose my parse app again, that i would like to use?

Comment: perhaps try 'parse new' in another directory which is empty, it will let you choose again

Comment: @Qiqi how can i do that? if it's easier i would uninstall it and do again.

Comment: Parse new command simply sets up the directory to grab your Javascript. It looks like you have already set up the directory for parse to use to deploy Javascript. You can simply delete that folder from your project in finder, you don't have to use terminal for that and then just repeat all steps from the guide. Hope that helps. Let me know.

Comment: @ITGronk It worked well. Please add it as an answer and i can accept is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parse new command simply sets up the directory to grab your Javascript. It looks like you have already set up the directory for parse to use to deploy Javascript. You can simply delete that folder from your project in finder, you don't have to use terminal for that and then just repeat all steps from the guide. Hope that helps. Let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I have face this problem...

it show error because you are already in Directory

you have to use this command in terminal  cd ..

then you can create new project or use exist project